# Hover div to show more things inside another div

Tags: html, show, slide, left-to-right

I'm working on a website and was looking for a function that lets me hover a div to scroll right inside another div, like this example:

See: http://jsfiddle.net/s17L50pv/1/

Imagine that the arrow `>` to the right is the div you hover and the content in `#slider` moves right, showing more books!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval()` and some events (`mouseover` and `mouseout`) to get this effect

See if that's what You are talking about - http://jsfiddle.net/s17L50pv/5/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Only things is that I want it to end when it comes to the last item in the list, and that you can go to the left again if you want, also if possible to make the slide go a bit faster when you hold the > button. Thank you very much!

Comment: For any complet solutions try to use sth like @Mario A has posted - ready javascript carousel script - http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @MichaelKutra Checked the website out. None of those was what I wanted, but yours was perfect. Can you PLEASE fix the slide to stop on last book and make it faster if you click the arrow? Also please make it slide back to left when you press that arrow! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a javascript carousel slider for this, there are tons of free scripts around, e.g:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/